# How to lowercase a portion of text using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following text:

`ABC=ABC.2016.001.02.Yomama.01234`

How to lowercase just the Yomama part. I'd like it to look like this:

`ABA.2016.001.02.yomama.01234`

How can I accomplish this with python?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want a generic solution (otherwise you could just use `str.replace()` with a hard coded string) you can split the string on the `.`, lowercase the string in the appropriate field, and then stitch it back together with `str.join()`:

```
s = 'ABC=ABC.2016.001.02.Yomama.01234'
fields = s.split('.')
fields[4] = fields[4].lower()
print('.'.join(fields))
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution, provided text ABC don't have repeating text

```
tmp = ABC.split('.')[-2]
ABC = ABC.replace(tmp, tmp.lower())
```